# Convergence of $ \sum_{x=2}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\ln\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I want to prove that the infinite series defines by:

$$ \sum_{x=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\ln\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x^2}\right)$$

converges.

I have shown that $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{\ln\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x^2} \right) = 0$$

But proving that $$ \frac{\ln\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x^2} $$
is monotonically decreasing appears too complicated.

Also i tried : 
 $$\frac{\ln\left(\ln(x)\right)}{x^2} =  \frac{\ln\left(\circ(x)\right)}{x^2} =  \frac{\circ\left(\circ(x)\right)}{x^2} = \circ\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
but there I know that the series converges so there has to be something wrong with my reasoning.

Any ideas?

(I consider $x$ to be of integer values, probably should have replaced with $n$ or $k$, but I think it's the same.)

Comment: For large $x$ we have $\ln x\lt x^{1/2}$.  Iterating this, we have $\ln(\ln x)\lt\ln(x^{1/2})={1\over2}\ln x\lt{1\over2}x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Wouldn't you need $x$ starting at 2?

Comment: One minor error: your function is not a number in $x=0$ and $x=1$ unless you entered the sequence incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah $x$ starts at $2$, force of of habit, i will edit that.
@BarryCipra could you give a more explicit solution. I didn't exactly get what you are getting at.

Comment: @IliasKoutroumpas, for large $x$, we wind up with $\sum{\ln(\ln x)\over x^2}\lt\sum{1\over x^{3/2}}$. Since $3/2\gt1$, the $p$-test tells us $\sum{1\over x^{3/2}}$ converges.

Comment: @BarryCipra Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @IliasKoutroumpas, you can post (and accept) an answer to your own question.

Comment: Indeed you needed the complete solution: $ln(x)<\sqrt x \to \ln(ln(x))<ln(\sqrt x)<\sqrt x$

$\dfrac{\ln(ln(x))}{x^2}<\dfrac{\sqrt x}{x^2}=\dfrac{1}{x^{3/2}}$

$\to \displaystyle \sum\dfrac{\ln(ln(x))}{x^2}<\sum\dfrac{1}{x^{3/2}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ermakoff' test:
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf(e^x)}{f(x)}=k<1 \Rightarrow \text{converges}.$$
The given series converges because:
$$\lim_\limits{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2 \cdot \ln x}{e^{x}\cdot \ln{(\ln x)}}=0.$$